# How to get firestore queried data from angular service to component

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to Firestore and async functions. Below function is in angular service:

```
 async verifyCredentials(loginFormData:any)
  {
    const q = query(collection(db, "users"), where("mobile", "==", loginFormData["mobile"]), where("email", "==", loginFormData["email"]));
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
    //console.log("data is:", querySnapshot.docs[0].data());
    return querySnapshot.docs[0].data();
  }
```

I am calling above function to get data in a component:

```
 onSubmit() {
    
    this.submitted = true;
    if (this.loginForm.invalid) {
        return;
    }
    if(this.submitted)
    {
      console.log(this.userService.verifyCredentials(this.loginForm.value)); 
      //this.router.navigate(['/menu']);
    }
  
  }
```

Below is the console output:

[image: Console]

Comment: "returning doc.data() is not working here" What does that mean? Which line of the code you shared doesn't do what you expect it to do? Is there an error message?

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete information @FrankvanPuffelen . I have updated the question. Please have a look. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked. I completely forget to use .then

```
onSubmit() { 
    this.submitted = true;
    if (this.loginForm.invalid) {
        return;
    }
    if(this.submitted)
    {
      this.userService.verifyCredentials(this.loginForm.value).then( data => 
      {
        console.log(data); 
      });
      //this.router.navigate(['/menu']);
    }
  }
```